# 'What does the abbreviation RE: means when referring to something?

Tags: meaning

What does 'RE means when referencing to something?

Comment: I always thought it was shorthand for "Regarding:"

Comment: What does RE stand for?
 
http://www.abbreviations.com/RE

Comment: (Uncapitalized) **re** is a word in and of itself, defined by OED as *Originally: in the matter of, referring to; Subsequently: about, concerning.* It derives from classical Latin **rē,** ablative of **rēs** thing, affair, and in the *original* usage as defined above, it was "short for" Latin **in re**.

Answer (score 5):

It's not an abbreviation.  It's from the Latin phrase [in re](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_re) meaning "In the matter of" that in English usage has been shortened (and on printed forms, often capitalized) to just [RE:](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/re)

Comment: The "in re" wording is still used in certain areas of U.S. law, perhaps most notably in the area of wills and estates, where adjudicated cases bear names such as [In re Estate of Gardiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_re_Estate_of_Gardiner).

Answer (score 0):

It comes from the Latin *res* meaning "thing" and means "in the matter of" or "regarding"

Comment: Not exactly 'comes from': it **is** the word *res*, in the ablative case.